# Get Section´s Title In UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I set all my titles´s section in my TableView.

Sometime later, i need to get the values of the title in any section´s tableview,

**How can i ask that values directly to the UITableView?**

Without the delegate protocol:

```
    [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:i]
```

Because this method overrides an protocol of my own class.

```
- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     /* If datasource methdod is implemented, get´s the name of sections*/
     SEL nameForSection = @selector(nameForSection:);
    if ( (self.dataSource) && [self.dataSource respondsToSelector:nameForSection] )
    {
       NSString *titleSection = [self.dataSource nameForSection:section];
       return titleSection;
   }

return nil;
```

}

Thanks Advance...

Comment: Try and give a little more detail to your question. To improve your chances of getting an answer try and implement some of these helpful ideas when asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table view method will return the view for header and I think in your case it should be `UILabel`

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: with this i get the UIView´s section, but i need just the text

Comment: NSLog it it can be a UILabel.. and if its a view then it must have a subview that is a UILabel

Answer (score 7):

*Start support from iOS6.0 and higher version*

You can get it like this if you have indexPath:

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView* header =[self.tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
NSLog(@"Header text = %@", header.textLabel.text);
```

Change it like this

```
header.textLabel.text= @"changed";
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the dataSource of the UITableView to get the section titles:

```
[tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
```

If you're using the default dataSource (i.e. the UITableViewController), it'll return the section title as set in InterfaceBuilder.

Here's my code that duplicates a template view and sets the title appropriately. Note that I simply use the table's header view as a convenient spot to store my template and remove it on viewDidLoad in my UITableViewController subclass.

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView* header = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.sectionHeaderTemplateView]];
    UILabel* label = ((UILabel*)header.subviews[0]);
    label.text = [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    return header;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the sections title in NSArray, and use this array to get the values of any section in table view.

Comment: I can't store any NSArray... I am implementing my on Protocol, that uses the UITableView´s protocol

Comment: But your code is providing the section titles to the table view when asked (titleForHeaderSection), so why do you not have them stored?

Comment: because this class to implement my protocol is required to store that information.

Answer (score 2):

How did you set the sections's titles ?
If you are overriding the tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: method from UITableViewDataSource, you can call it yourself to get title for a specific section.
If you are overriding the tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method from UITableViewDataSource, think about having an array containing all your labels, so that you can get label's title for a specific section.

Comment: I am implementing my own Protol, that overrides the UItableView´s protocol.

Comment: so if i asked the title with that method i am asking the class that is implementing my protocol...

Comment: I don't understand your problem, you are implementing you own protocol that overrides which protocol of UITableView, dataSource or delegate ? UITableView is not going to call new methods of your own protocol, so why are you creating you own protocol ?

Comment: I am creating my own SideBar like Facebook app, in a Protocol way. That protocol overrides all the UITableView methods. The class with implement my own protocol give all the info for the tableView, but i wan t to create  method that returns the title for an section.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     /* If datasource methdod is implemented, get´s the name of sections*/
     SEL nameForSection = @selector(nameForSection:);
    if ( (self.dataSource) && [self.dataSource respondsToSelector:nameForSection] )
    {
       NSString *titleSection = [self.dataSource nameForSection:section];
       return titleSection;
   }

return nil;
```

Hum... Your DataSource have a DataSource ?
The goal of the UITableView's dataSource is to be implemented by an other class, so self.datasource is not the datasource of UITableView !

Comment: some like that, because my protocol create an UITableView and UIViewController, (like Facebook app). So i have create some protocols to have the data to my tableview